# How to escape a StringTemplate template?

Tags: java, antlr, stringtemplate-4

I am trying to process the template (see below) and I'm getting all sorts of messages in the eclipse console.

I've searched the net but can't really find what I'm looking for. I recall seeing something on this topic here but I didn't bookmark it at the time and cannot find it again! :/

Can you please help? thanks

ps. I'm trying to construct an email message using StringTemplate. and using HTML tags for "easier reading" for our clients.

**java code used to load my template**

```
STGroup stGroup = new STGroupDir("/resources/emailTemplates", '$', '$');
ST emailBody = stGroup.getInstanceOf("Fab");
```

**my template**

```
<h3>Thank you for submitting your details.</h3>
Student ID: $studentId$<br />
Family Name: $familyName$<br />
Given Name: $givenName$<br />
Gender: $gender$<br />Course: $course$<br />
<h3>This is the final confirmation for MyApps Arrival Briefing (FAB).</h3>
$first$
</p><p>
$previous$
<p></p>
<p>If you have to cancel a booking please notify us by email: <a href="mailto:issu@">issu@myapps.com</a>. <br>For booking an additional event please revisit the <a href="http://www.myapps.com/international-students/services/">ISSU website</a> and submit another booking. <br>If you have difficulties finding the venues please ask for help at ISSU. <br><br>The ISSU is located in the basement (B 10)</a> of the Union building (building 25 on the <a href="http://www.myapps.com/MyApps/app_templates/behaviours/popup.cfm?file_uuid=90DE8CF7-C571-D75A-CB7A-37DA9D470AB4&amp;method=popup&amp;alt=%27MyApps%20Map%20showing%20ISSU%20location_thumb.png">campus map</a>).</p>
```

**Here's the error messages I get about my template**

```
Fab.st 1:1: invalid character '<'
Fab.st 1:3: invalid character '>'
Fab.st 1:1: no viable alternative at input 'h3'
Fab.st 1:43: invalid character '<'
Fab.st 1:44: invalid character '/'
Fab.st 1:46: invalid character '>'
Fab.st 2:12: invalid character '$'
Fab.st 2:22: invalid character '$'
Fab.st 2:24: invalid character '<'
Fab.st 2:28: invalid character '/'
Fab.st 2:28: invalid character '>'
Fab.st 3:13: invalid character '$'
Fab.st 3:24: invalid character '$'
Fab.st 3:26: invalid character '<'
Fab.st 3:30: invalid character '/'
Fab.st 3:30: invalid character '>'
Fab.st 4:12: invalid character '$'
Fab.st 4:22: invalid character '$'
Fab.st 4:24: invalid character '<'
Fab.st 4:28: invalid character '/'
Fab.st 4:28: invalid character '>'
Fab.st 5:8: invalid character '$'
Fab.st 5:15: invalid character '$'
Fab.st 5:17: invalid character '<'
Fab.st 5:21: invalid character '/'
Fab.st 5:21: invalid character '>'
Fab.st 5:30: invalid character '$'
Fab.st 5:37: invalid character '$'
Fab.st 5:39: invalid character '<'
Fab.st 5:43: invalid character '/'
Fab.st 5:43: invalid character '>'
Fab.st 6:1: invalid character '<'
Fab.st 6:3: invalid character '>'
Fab.st 6:72: invalid character '<'
Fab.st 6:73: invalid character '/'
Fab.st 6:75: invalid character '>'
Fab.st 7:0: invalid character '$'
Fab.st 7:6: invalid character '$'
Fab.st 8:1: invalid character '<'
Fab.st 8:2: invalid character '/'
Fab.st 8:3: invalid character '>'
Fab.st 8:5: invalid character '<'
Fab.st 8:6: invalid character '>'
Fab.st 9:0: invalid character '$'
Fab.st 9:9: invalid character '$'
Fab.st 10:1: invalid character '<'
Fab.st 10:2: invalid character '>'
Fab.st 10:4: invalid character '<'
Fab.st 10:5: invalid character '/'
Fab.st 10:6: invalid character '>'
Fab.st 11:1: invalid character '<'
Fab.st 11:2: invalid character '>'
Fab.st 11:63: invalid character '<'
Fab.st 11:99: invalid character '>'
Fab.st 11:121: invalid character '<'
Fab.st 11:122: invalid character '/'
Fab.st 11:123: invalid character '>'
Fab.st 11:127: invalid character '<'
Fab.st 11:129: invalid character '>'
Fab.st 11:182: invalid character '<'
Fab.st 11:250: invalid character '>'
Fab.st 11:264: invalid character '<'
Fab.st 11:265: invalid character '/'
Fab.st 11:266: invalid character '>'
Fab.st 11:297: invalid character '<'
Fab.st 11:299: invalid character '>'
Fab.st 11:374: invalid character '<'
Fab.st 11:376: invalid character '>'
Fab.st 11:378: invalid character '<'
Fab.st 11:380: invalid character '>'
Fab.st 11:420: invalid character '1'
Fab.st 11:421: invalid character '0'
Fab.st 11:424: invalid character '<'
Fab.st 11:425: invalid character '/'
Fab.st 11:426: invalid character '>'
Fab.st 11:460: invalid character '2'
Fab.st 11:461: invalid character '5'
Fab.st 11:471: invalid character '<'
Fab.st 11:678: invalid character '>'
Fab.st 11:690: invalid character '<'
Fab.st 11:691: invalid character '/'
Fab.st 11:692: invalid character '>'
Fab.st 11:696: invalid character '<'
Fab.st 11:697: invalid character '/'
Fab.st 11:698: invalid character '>'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

StringTemplate 4 uses a new format for loose templates (`*.st` files) so they perform better with the new parameter passing scheme used in the internal bytecode representation. Template files which used to look like this:

**example.st** (version 3)

```
Student ID: $studentId$<br />
Family Name: $familyName$<br />
Given Name: $givenName$<br />
```

Would now look like this:

**example.st** (version 4)

```
example(studentId, familyName, givenName) ::= <<
Student ID: $studentId$<br />
Family Name: $familyName$<br />
Given Name: $givenName$<br />
>>
```

If you don't want to alter your templates to include the prototypes, you can use [`STRawGroupDir`](http://www.stringtemplate.org/api/org/stringtemplate/v4/STRawGroupDir.html) instead of [`STGroupDir`](http://www.stringtemplate.org/api/org/stringtemplate/v4/STGroupDir.html), which was [added in ST 4.0.5](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ST4/4.0.5+Release+Notes).

Answer (score 1):

This is the link that tells how to ensure html entities are escape in string template, 
[What is the best way to ensure HTML entities are escaped in StringTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14331081/what-is-the-best-way-to-ensure-html-entities-are-escaped-in-stringtemplate)

Answer (score 0):

See this post, I think it answers your question: [How to exclude specific folders or files from validation in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272237/how-to-exclude-specific-folders-or-files-from-validation-in-eclipse)

You would just exclude *.st files from being validated.